# SQL select multiple rows and order them by id

Tags: sql, select

I got a `Student` with a few parameters, like Id, Name, etc.
Now I got another one table called `ACCOUNTS`, they have an id and a name...

the relation between these two is `OneToMany` (one student can have more accounts)

and i need a SQL query to show all accounts for the student...here is what i have, but it's not working...

```
"Select distinct s from Student s left join fetch s.accounts where s.id=:studId"
```

I should say that the `Student` has a field called `accounts`

And at the end of the query, i placed already `ORDER BY` and then the following code didn't work:

```
s.accounts.id
account.id
student.account.id
```

So...long story short...the query above, shows the accounts of the specific student...now i just need to order them by the id of the accounts

Any suggestions?

Comment: `from Student s left join accounts a on s.id = a.id`?

Comment: Also, you are aliasing two things with the same name `s`.

Comment: it does not work...

Comment: and i have to do it, bc s has that atribute

Comment: Which RDBMS ???

Comment: so the student has a field called accounts, and i need to show them....that works, but i need to order them....

Comment: i have no idea how to answer u that...

Comment: so i just need to order it by the id of the accounts...everything else works

Comment: `select distinct s.id, s.name, a.id from students s left outer join accounts a on  s.id = a.id order by s.id, a.id;`

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc..

Comment: I am using WildFly on eclipse JBOS

Comment: and the code above worked...thx man

Answer (score 1):

As OP confirmed adding it as answer.

```
select distinct s.id, s.name, a.id 
from students s left outer join accounts a on s.id = a.id 
order by s.id, a.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

> > one student can have more accounts

So it's two tables:

- student (id, name, ...)
- accounts (id, student_id, ...)

> > I should say that the Student has a field called accounts

That makes no sense. By this you would store *one* account per student and several students could share one account. So I stick to the first statement that one student can have several accounts and the tables look more or less like I've shown above.

You want to see accounts for one student. So you select from accounts where the student ID matches:

```
select * from accounts where student_id = :studId order by account.id;
```

If you want to show student data along, you'd join the tables instead:

```
select * 
from student s
left join accounts a on a.student_id = s.id
where s.id = :studId
order by a.id;
```